NVIDIA driver update causes incredible lag
I have 5 monitors attached to 2 GPUs and when i booted Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for the first time they all worked.
After completing the installation my extra monitors attached to my second GPU stopped working completely.
I looked around online and found the solution to be to install nvidia-driver-470 as told here.
This made the remaining screens work but it also caused my whole system to lag like crazy.
After looking into the system monitor it says that my CPUs are almost at max load which I don't know what that means but my guess is its using my CPU instead of my GPUs.
Also I don't see any GPU in the list of things on the system monitor but I'm new to Ubuntu so i don't know if that's normal
System Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
CPU: Intel I5-9400F
GPU #1: NVIDIA RTX 2060
GPU #2 NVIDIA GT 730
RAM: 32G
Edit: removing 2 of the monitors seems to have temporarily fixed the issue but it's strange that on Windows 10 I can run all these monitors at 60hz no problem while on Ubuntu I have issues.
What gave me the hint to the fact that I was overstressing the second GPU was user generix saying the following here

My advice: don’t do that. If you want a monitor to display more than just the desktop background, you’ll need about 1.3GB video memory per 4k monitor (FHD:350MB) on the primary graphics card, with three enabled monitors, you were at 3.1GB/4GB already. if you run out of VMEM, the gpu will start using system memory and everything will come down to a crawl.

